# self-closing tags with XMLEventWriter

Tags: java, xml, stax

So the question is pretty much as stated in the title.  I am doing some xml work and using XMLEventWriter.  The big issue I'm having is that I need to create some self closing tags

The problem is that I haven't figured out a way to do this with the eventWriter.  I have tried everything I can think of using XMLEventFactory but nothing seems to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible using [XMLEventWriter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html). It is certainly possible with [XMLStreamWriter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeEmptyElement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

If you are stuck with XMLEventWriter, you could transform the data afterwards.

```
Reader xml = new StringReader("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><foo></foo>");
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml),
    new StreamResult(System.out));
```

The output of the above code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo/>
```

Comment: Looks like XMLStreamWriter may be my best choice.  Transforming would be the optimal solution but when i'm dealing with 400+ mb files that will be a serious time problem.

Comment: With XMLStreamWriter you can use writeEmptyElement(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980516/how-to-write-self-closing-element-tags-using-xmlstreamwriter (leaving here as a quick reference)