# How to write self-closing element tags using XMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, self

I am trying to write a XML element tag that has to look like this :

`<case type="" player=""/>`

My code is :

`doc.writeStartElement("case");`
`doc.writeAttribute("type", type);`
`doc.writeAttribute("player", "");`
`doc.writeEndElement();`

But, as I expected, a closing tag is added at the end, so it looks like this :

`<case type="" player=""></case>`

I am trying to write a self closing element tag, but cannot find how.
Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Do you really need that?  the two forms are equivalent

Comment: Our teacher has given us some XML files with the self closing elements, but I don't know if it will make a real difference if I write mine with the closing tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `writeEmptyElement()`.

But you should be aware that both forms are [semantically equivalent](http://www.xml.com/axml/notes/EMPTY3.html), so any requirement that differentiates them should be viewed with suspicion.

Comment: bummer want to vote up my comment it was really the first correct response :-(

Comment: Excel requires the `dimension` tag to be self-closing. Of course, I'm not saying Microsoft shouldn't be viewed with suspicion

Answer (score 0):

BY writing `writeEndElement();` you are asking the library to close `case` for you,
instead you should not invoke it and invoke `writeEndDocument()` instead.